# How to get TinyMCE and Jquery validate to work together?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate and the jquery version of tinymce.

I found this piece of code that makes tinymce to validate itself every time something changes in it.

Hi

I am using the jquery validate with my jquery tinymce so I have this in my code

```
    // update validation status on change
    onchange_callback: function (editor)
    {
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        $("#" + editor.id).valid();
    },
```

This works however there is one problem. If a user copies something from word it brings all that junk styling with it what is usually over 50,000 characters. This is way over my amount of characters a user is allowed to type in.

So my jquery validation method goes off telling me that they went over the limit. In the mean time though tinymce has cleaned up that mess and it could be possible now the user has not gone over the limit.

Yet the message is still there.

So is there a better function call I can put this in? Maybe tell tinymce to delay the valid when a paste is happening, or maybe a different callback?

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh yeah, I also faced this problem.

So, I fixed it by calling the validation on the click event of a button instead.

```
$("#buttontosave").click(function() {
         tinyMCE.triggerSave();
         var status;
         status = $("#myform").valid(); //Validate again
         if(status==true) { 
             //Carry on
         }
         else { }
});
```

This works try it.

For additional resources try

http://rmurphey.com/blog/2009/01/12/jquery-validation-and-tinymce/

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=21588

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Jquery/Q_23941005.html

Comment: LOL. I tried that and thought it did not work. Apparently I was submitting the wrong form when I tried it. When you suggested it I tried it another form that submitted the right one lol. So now it works. Would have been nice to do it on change but this is good too.

Answer (score 11):

After hours of fiddling out how to get validation working with a TinyMCE editor i finally found that it is necessary to tell the validation plugin to NOT ignore hidden fields (as the original textarea is hidden when tinyMCE is initialised). So the solution in short is to:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ''
});
```

This code tells the jquery Validation Plugin to check hidden fields as well... And then you can normally...

```
 onchange_callback: function (editor)
{
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    $("#" + editor.id).valid();
},
```

This isn't a direct answer to the original question - i know. But since this page is #1 by google for "jquery validate tinymce" i think it's a good place to mention it here.

danludwig mentioned this here: [Unable to get TinyMCE working with jQuery Unobtrusive Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858591/unable-to-get-tinymce-working-with-jquery-unobtrusive-validation)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Long time ago this wasn't necessary, and today, after jquery and validator update I notices that old code stopped working. And this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the content of the editor has not yet been copied into the related textarea when validation is run. The solution suggested at http://rmurphey.com/blog/2009/01/12/jquery-validation-and-tinymce/ works for me. I generalized it a little bit because in my scenario the number of textareas and their IDs were not known before runtime.

So in the click event handler I copy the values over manually for each TinyMCE editor:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tinyMCE.editors.length; i++) {
    var textarea = tinyMCE.editors[i].getElement();
    var newText = tinyMCE.editors[i].getContent();      
    $(tinyMCE.editors[i].getElement()).text(newText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Willhelm who give me the idea (unfortunately his code didn't work if you had more than one textarea in your form).

This is the correct way to do it:

```
    tinymce.init({
        setup: function(ed){
            ed.on("blur", function () {
                $("#" + ed.id).val(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
            });
        }
    }
```

This way we don't need to touch the validator code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had some related difficulties with the timing of when event handlers fire, particularly as the size of the character buffer pasted in from Word increases.  The event I was interested in was the key-up: as the user types into a headline field (for a blog post), the app updates an auto-generated permalink field. I ended up with a belt-and-suspenders approach: handle the key-up and handle the change event, just in case.  An abridged version of my code:

```
hdlHeadlineChange = function (code) {

    //NOTES: The 'code' argument is for debugging purposes only: it helps you
    //figure out which event has fired.

    var headlineText = $(tinyMCE.selectedInstance.getBody()).text();

    //heuristically detect and ignore text with embedded Microsoft Word markup
    if (headlineText.match(/<!--/)) {
        return;
    }

    //as a backstop, trim excessively long text to fit database maximum lengths
    var truncateLength;    
    var semanticTitle = replaceSpecialCharactersInSemanticUrl(headlineText);

    //trim the permalink to fit the 255-character max in the database            
    truncateLength = 255 - $('#permalinkPreface').text().length;
    $('#permalinkSpan').text(semanticTitle.substring(0, truncateLength));
};

function setupHeadlineEventHandlers() {
    tinyMCE.get("headline").onKeyUp.add(function(ed, evt) {
        hdlHeadlineChange(evt.keyCode);
    });

    //NOTES: This handler is sort of a backstop.  Although the key-up handler may see text
    //with markup, we expect that the change handler will not.
    $('#headline').change(function () {
        hdlHeadlineChange(-1);
    });
}
```

The key point is that I used .change() to arm the event handler, rather than onchange_callback.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me... I added value of tiny field to textarea

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var form_validator = $("#form").validate({...});
});

function Valid()
{   
var content= tinyMCE.get('desc').getContent();
$('#desc').val(content);
    return false;
}

<form id='form' onSubmit='return Valid();'>
<textarea id='desc'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
    var form = $('form').validate({ .... });

    tinyMCE.init({

        .....

        setup: function(ed){
            ed.on('blur', function() {
                $("textarea").html( tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() );
            });
        }
    });
```

I hope this works for you, too

Answer (score 0):

See this demo here for the latest documentation about jquery.validation and tinymce together: https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/tinymce/

**There are a few parts to it:**

1. Even though tinymce's textarea is hidden, we need to whitelist the element so the validator can be run on it.

   ```
   $.validator.setDefaults({
       ignore: ":hidden:not(.rich-text-editor)"
   });
   ```
2. Initialize tinymce so that it persists its value to the underlying `textarea` on change.

   ```
   tinymce.init({
       selector: 'textarea.rich-text-editor',
       init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
           // update validation status on change`
           editor.on("Change", function (e) {
               tinyMCE.triggerSave();
               $(editor.targetElm).valid();
           });
       }
   });
   ```
3. Persist the underlying `textarea`s before submitting any form.

   ```
   var forms = $("form");
   if (forms.length > 0) {
       var validator = forms.submit(function () {
           // update underlying textarea before submit validation
           tinyMCE.triggerSave();
       }).validate();
   ```
4. Update the `validator`'s `focusInvalid` function to treat tinymce's textareas special

   ```
       validator.focusInvalid = function () {
           // put focus on tinymce on submit validation
           if (this.settings.focusInvalid) {
               try {
                   var toFocus = $(this.findLastActive() || this.errorList.length && this.errorList[0].element || []);
                   if (toFocus.is("textarea")) {
                       tinyMCE.get(toFocus.attr("id")).focus();
                   } else {
                       toFocus.filter(":visible").focus();
                   }
               } catch (e) {
                   // ignore IE throwing errors when focusing hidden elements
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**Note:** You may want to surround your tinymce code by the following block in case there is an issue loading tinymce (or the JS is not included on certain pages.)

```
if (typeof tinymce !== "undefined")
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the answer with more detail.