# Can't validate TinyMCE 4 control in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation, tinymce-4

I'm using MVC4 with *knockoutjs* (with mapping plugin) and the binding plugin for *tinymce* (which defines the "*wysiwyg*" binding to associate a textarea to a *TinyMCE* editor) . Everything works fine except that I've been unsuccessfully trying to get unobtrusive validation to work in *TinyMCE* controls. As you will see, I've applied several of the suggested solutions found here and in google but none works.

The *TinyMCE* (and also *TinyMCE jquery*) version is 4.0.26

The involved parts of the code are as follow:

***.CS*** (only the property associated with the TinyMCE control)

```
    [AllowHtml]
    [LocRequired]
    [LocDisplayName(Consts.LBL_TXT_EN)]
    public string Text_en { get; set; }
```

The "*Loc*" prefixed attributes inherit from *RequiredAttribute* and *DisplayNameAttribute* data annotation classes  and were made to also retrieve localized texts from the DB. They work fine, so assume they are regular *Required* and *DisplayName* attributes. There are other similar properties: *Text_es*, *Text_de*, etc which should have a similar set of attributes, but for now I'm only setting the *LocRequired* in *Text_en*, until the problem solves.

***.CSHTML:***

```
<td>
    <div class="editor-label required">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text_en)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text_en,new{data_bind="wysiwyg:Text_en"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text_en)
    </div>
</td>
```

I have several of those, for the other properties mentioned above, each one with their corresponding setting of course.

***javascript:*** (see the comments in code) . I've already applied the "ignore" option for the validator, the tinymce.triggerSave(), and a form.validate() definition and nothing works

```
$(function()
{
...
    var mapping = 
    {
        create: function(options)
        {
            var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
            ...
            ...
            vm.acceptDataEdit = function() //this is associated with the click event "Save" button in the form
            {
                tinymce.triggerSave(); //Almost every search on google says it solves the problem... Well, here it doesn't
                var ok = frm.valid(); //Validation works for other fields but not for the tinymce
                if (ok)
                {
                    ...//posts the data
                }
                return false;
            }

            ko.editable(vm);// ko.editable(this);
            return vm;
        }
    }

        ko.bindingHandlers['wysiwyg'].defaults =
    {

    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
         "searchreplace  visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "table directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
    ],
    forced_root_block : false,
    force_br_newlines : true,
    force_p_newlines : false,
    content_css: "css/content.css",
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | l      ink image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons", 
    style_formats: [
         {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
         {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
         {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
         {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
         {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
         {title: 'Table styles'},
         {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ]
    };

    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(vData, mapping);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: '' }); // again, this is supposed to make the validator process the hidden text areas, but nothing happens

});
```

and I also tried adding, after the *setDefaults* line, equally without result:

```
frm.validate({
    rules: {
        Text_en:
        {
            required: true
        }
    }});
```

Any other suggestions? Do I have something wrong here?

Comment: it solved my problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10858712/995762)

Comment: Thanks. I've  already checked that. From the accepted post of that link is where I took almost all the stuff mentioned above. I finally could make it work but implementing what is in the next one (Brian Surowiec's): making the textareas show offscreen. I'll create an answer post with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It finally worked. Thanks to @marathonman I rechecked the posts of the [link he provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858591/unable-to-get-tinymce-working-with-jquery-unobtrusive-validation/10858712#10858712) (previously, the accepted one was the source for what i had already done), but this time I also looked at the Brian Surowiec's post  (I'll upvote these two posts when I have enough credits to be able to vote) and following his advice of making the textareas to be shown off-screen was what made it work. So I added just what he did:

```
var offCss = { position: 'absolute', height: 0, width: 0, top: -100 };
$('#Text_en').css(offCss);
$('#Text_es').css(offCss);
...//and the same for the others

//after that called show() for them
$('#Text_en').show();
$('#Text_es').show();
...//and so on
```

And that was all. By the way : of the other code I posted , the frm.validate code i tried before, was not needed at all, everything else was kept.